# Big O notation for quicksort implementation

Tags: java, sorting, complexity, quick-sort

I am trying to find out what would be the Big O notation of a quick sort implementation I wrote. If I can get some analysis on the code, that would be great.

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[] input = { 23, 31, 1, 21, 36, 72};
    System.out.println("Before sorting : " + Arrays.toString(input));
    quickSort(input); // sort the integer array using quick sort algorithm
    System.out.println("After sorting : " + Arrays.toString(input));

    // input with duplicates
    int[] withDuplicates = { 11, 14, 16, 12, 11, 15};
    System.out.println("Before sorting : " + Arrays.toString(withDuplicates));
    quickSort(withDuplicates); // sort the integer array using quick sort algorithm
    System.out.println("After sorting : " + Arrays.toString(withDuplicates));
}

/**
 * public method exposed to client, sorts given array using QuickSort
 * Algorithm in Java
 * @param array
 */
public static void quickSort(int[] array) {
   if(array.length <= 1) return;
   int leftwall = 0;
   int rightwall  = array.length - 1 ;
   int pivot = array[array.length/2]; 
   rechelperquickSort(array,leftwall,rightwall,pivot); 
}


public static void rechelperquickSort(int[] array ,int left , int right , int pivot ){

    int idx;   
    idx = left;

    if(left>=right) return;

    while(idx<=right){

        if(pivot > array[idx])swapinarray(array,left++,idx);

        idx++;
    }
    if(left >= right) return;
    pivot = array[left+1];
    rechelperquickSort(array,left+1,right,pivot);
    rechelperquickSort(array,0,left,array[left/2]);
}

public static void swapinarray(int[] array,int leftelementidx, int rightelementidx){
    int tmp = array[leftelementidx];
    array[leftelementidx] = array[rightelementidx];
    array[rightelementidx] = tmp;    
}

}
```

Comment: If it is quick sort then you already know it, if it is not same as quick sort then how can you call it quick sort?

Comment: [Wikipedia: Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) will tell you the answer your looking for.

Comment: if the prog selects `pivot' randomly, it will achieve better average performance.

Comment: it appears that you have not tested your own code. please run the code and test it to make sure that the code functions the way you anticipate it should.

Answer (score 7):

### Doesn't work

Your sort doesn't work on this array:

```
int[] input = { 4, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1};
```

The output is:

```
Before sorting : [4, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1]
After sorting : [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6]
```

### What's wrong?

One problem with your quicksort is that it doesn't always rearrange items to the left and right of the pivot.  If you pick the pivot that is the smallest element in the array, no swaps will be made.  Thus, you should either pick the leftmost item to be the pivot so that "no swaps" will just work, or swap the pivot item into the correct spot after your loop is finished.

Another problem with it is that you have a hardcoded 0 which is wrong:

```
rechelperquickSort(array,0,left,array[left/2]);
```

That `0` there should be the original value of `left` passed into the array.  Otherwise you are creating more work.

Answer (score 6):

Some stylistic comments.

**Spacing**

The proper use of white space makes a big difference for code readability. You use white space inconsistently, which suggests a lack of attention to your code, and differently than Java standards, both of which make me want to read and understand your code less. So:

Method definitions should be arranged as such

```
                        ▼
swapInArray(int[] array, int leftelementidx, int rightelementidx)
```

Method calls should abide by the same rules

```
                         ▼         ▼          ▼
rechelperquickSort(array, leftwall, rightwall, pivot);
```

Operators should be separated by a space ....

```
//DO
(idx >= right)

//DON'T
(idx>=right)
```

**Camel Case**

All variable/method/class names should comply with camel casing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). The lack of doing so makes it harder to read your variable names and also strays from standard naming schemes. The following

```
swapinarray(...)

//should be replaced with
swapInArray(...)
```

**Names**

You should strive to name your methods so well that someone knows what the method does without reading the implementation.

```
//I immediately know what this method does
swapInArray(...)

//I have no idea what this method does and need to read its implementation
rechelperquickSort
```

On another note, as I wrote that last method definition, I realized that it means "Recursive Helper Quick Sort". The first time I read it, I read "Rechel Per Quick Sort". Which is why you want to use Camel Casing.

**Method Visibility**

You correctly point out in your JavaDoc command that quickSort(int[] array) is your public API. But you don't enforce this by leaving the two helper method public as well. By leaving the helper methods open, you leave an easily misused method available to be called, namely rechelperquickSort(); Imagine a client who doesn't know better makes the following call

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
rechelperquickSort(a, 5, -3, 16);
```

Your code quickly crashes due to IndexOutOfBoundsException. If you make this method private, you'll never deal with this error, and people who use your API will have one less method to try to understand. Better for everyone.

Comment: I agree about the naming. `swapinarray()` could just be `swap()`, and `rechelperquickSort()` could just be `private static void quickSort()` (taking advantage of overloading).